# how do the integer value relate to colors in the setTextColor(int color) in android studio?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a specific question about Android.  Using setTextColor,

the developers guide shows void setTextColor (int color).  Ok checking stackoverflow syntax is myObjectName.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)

Can someone explain the integer value in setTextColor(int color) and what integer values as they relate to colors?

I know the hex value color code, just don't understand how this relates to the integer value.

Comment: You could just write a util class that has those corresponding values as INTs but underneath, you have the actual hex?

Answer (score 1):

Android has a [Color class.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).. the

```
android.graphics.Color
```

and every Color you get when you call

**Color**.*aColor* is in the class defined as a constant. Example

[image]

so for example:

**Color.BLACK** is mapped to a integer value, in this case

```
int BLACK
Constant Value: -16777216 (0xff000000)
```

and as you can imagine that value in hex is related aswell to a RGB+Alpha value

so at the end:

```
Color.BLACK = -16777216 = 0xff000000
                             | | | |
                        alpha  | | |
                              Red| |
                              Green|
                                Blue
```

**why an integer?** well every color can take a value between 0 and 255 (8 bits exactly) and you can perfectly match
Red
Green
Blue and
Alpha, all those a 8 bits makes 32 bits which can be represented with an integer

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I get the hex representation.  Just don't understand how the method setTextColor(int color) is expecting an integer input and how it relates that to the color class?

Comment: This explanation helped me so much, THANKS!